# Large Titles Not Being Set Via Extension [Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, preferslargetitles

I have an extension to configure my `UINavigationController` with large titles which I call in `ViewDidLoad` of my controller;

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    func configure(with title: String) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = title
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    }
}
```

This extension doesn't seem to be called, however, when I place:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Into my `ViewDidLoad`, it works as expected. any ideas on why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` it refers to `ViewController.navigationController`.

But your extension is for `UINavigationController` so it refers `ViewController.navigationController.navigationController`

Just replace this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

With this:

```
navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and call this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
navigationController?.configure(with: "")
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the above and it had showed the large title however, it didn't give me the title string. I've now made the extension against the ViewController instead of the NavController.

Comment: Yes, it could be an alternative. Glad the problem was solved.